# how to label topics automatically after applying LDA

Tags: python, nltk, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

i have implemented LDA in python.now i want to label the topics whichever i got from LDA.

```
[(0, u'0.023*"alternate" + 0.023*"transfervisions" + 0.013*"tvcommunity"'), (1, u'0.026*"minimalism" + 0.026*"minimalist" + 0.018*"honking"'), (2, u'0.027*"videomaking" + 0.019*"python" + 0.019*"httpstcoc2ythrctki"')]
```

Comment: And the question is? Provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

Answer (score 2):

Most creators of topic models assign the labels to the topics **manually**.

Automated labeling is perhaps possible for English language (with lots of rich language resources around), for some hints see these question on other Stackexchange sites and their answers:

- [How to give name to topics created using LDA?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9663/how-to-give-name-to-topics-created-using-lda)
- [Labeling documents with short text labels after topic modeling?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238382/labeling-documents-with-short-text-labels-after-topic-modeling)
- [Assigning meaningful cluster name automatically](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104385/assigning-meaningful-cluster-name-automatically)

Answer (score 1):

You might try using word vectors to average the top N words in a topic and then using the cosine similarity to find the closest word in the corpus?